# Redshift table with UTF-8 char upload issue

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8, amazon-redshift

I am trying to copy into a redshift table some data that happen to display some UTF-8 characters (Portuguese accented letters).

I create a table setting VARCHAR(256) data type where needed, as suggested in other answers.

When I copy the table, all the special characters are uploaded as question marks (e.g. "Boleto de cobran?a") as per specification ACCEPTINVCHARS AS '?'.

To preserve the special characters I encoded my cvs file as UTF-8 using Blocknotes, but when i do it all of a sudden I start getting errors and I am no longer able to copy the data.

Code wise i used:

```
dbGetQuery(myRedshift$con, "CREATE TABLE <NAME_OF_MY_TABLE> (
<VARIABLE_1>                        VARCHAR(256) sortkey distkey,            
<VARIABLE_2>                        NUMERIC(10,2),
<VARIABLE_3>                        INTEGER)")

dbGetQuery(myRedshift$con, "<NAME_OF_MY_TABLE> from 
's3://<S3_FOLDER_NAME>/<DATABASE_NAME.csv' 
CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=<MY_KEY>;aws_secret_access_key 
<MY_SA_KEY>'            
       region '<S3_REGION>'
       CSV DELIMITER ','
       NULL '#NULO'
       IGNOREHEADER 1")
```

The error i get is the following;

Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  Load into table '' failed.  Check 'stl_load_errors' system table for details.
)
NULL
    Warning message:
    In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :
    Could not create executecopy  from 
    's3://s3:///;aws_secret_access_key='
     region ''
     CSV DELIMITER ','
     NULL '#NULO'
     IGNOREHEADER 1

Thanks for any help.
Best,

Comment: See "question mark" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored  If that does not lead you to the answer, do the debugging it suggests and add then info to your question.

Comment: That helped. Thanks Rick!